# Use window.location.hash to change the background color of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following code is just for example, I want to use `window.location.hash` so that if someone opens a website like this,

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/2uPEs/3#row=green|red
```

They get `#green` row click triggered and `#box` color should be red,

Now I must need to show the `background-color` in URL, in example it's static but in real case scenario, it will be dynamic.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="a-class">
    <table id="maTable" class="ma-table">
        <tr class="row">
            <td><div id="green">green</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><div id="blue">blue</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="b"  class="b-class">
    <div id="box" class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a-class{ width:300px; height:200px; background-color:gray; float:left;}
.b-class{ width:300px; height:200px; float:right;}
.row {  background-color: #ccc; float: left; margin: 10px 0; padding: 1em; width: 50%; }
.box{ width:50%; height:50%; border-style:solid;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#green").click(function() {
        $("#box").css("background-color","red");
    });

     $("#blue").click(function() {
        $("#box").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2uPEs/3/).

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using # instead of ?row=

Comment: ?row= would invoke a new URL load at run time.  No reason for that if it is all handled by the client.

Comment: You could use the `:target` selector. It is also implemented in jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/target-selector/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/46/

get url from widow and manipulate it to get requred values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var url = window.location.pathname;
 //var url = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/2uPEs/3#row=green|red";
 var sUrl = url.split("#")[1];
 var arr =  sUrl.split("|");
 var bdColor = arr[1];
 var rowColor = arr[0].split("row=");
 alert("box color: "+ bdColor+ " row color" + rowColor);


});
```

Comment: Awlad, thanks but this is not what I am looking for :(, what I want is, when I click on green, it should change url and then add stuff to it using location.hash, and when someone go to the url with hash tags, it implements them

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is, when I click on `green`, it should change URL

You need to bind a click handler for the elements (`defElm` variable in the following) to change the `window.location.hash`.

> and when someone go to the URL with hash tags, it implements them

So, You could bind a handler to `window.onhashchange` event, split the *hash* string to get the variables, and change the `#box` background color.

Here you go:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  var defElm = [
    {
      'element': 'green',
      'color': 'red'
    },
    {
      'element': 'blue',
      'color': 'yellow'
    }
  ];

  $.each(defElm, function(i, v){
    $("#" + v.element).click(function() {
      window.location.hash = "#row="+ v.element + "|" + v.color;
    });
  });

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var _hash = window.location.hash.trim().split('|'),
        elm = _hash[0].substr(5) || false;
        clr = _hash[1]           || '';

    if (elm) {
      $("#" + elm).click(function() {
        $("#box").css("background-color", clr);
      }).click(); // trigger the click handler
    }
  });

});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yawimohi/3/edit)**.

**Note:** You probably need to download the *Bin* demo into your computer to check the effect (open the downloaded file in your web browser).

Comment: +1, thanks not allowed to download anything, so can't test it

Comment: @CustomizedName Just click on the `Bins` item at the top menu bar, then click on the *Download*.